# Work around Safari table colspan/writing-mode width bug

Tags: css, safari, html-table, webkit, flexbox

I'd like a table to have a first cell which colspans several cells and the ones beneath to have vertical text, like the following example.

```css
.second td * {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<table border=1><tr>
<td colspan=4>This cell has colspan=4</td>
</tr><tr class="second">
<td><div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div></td>
<td><div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div></td>
<td><div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div></td>
<td><div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div></td>
</tr></table>

<table border=1><tr>
<td colspan=4>This cell has colspan=4</td>
</tr><tr class="second">
<td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
<td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
<td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
<td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

In every browser except Safari, this produces properly-sized cells containing sideways text. Safari either collapses them (if the container is block) or expands them as if they were horizontal (if the container is inline).

I've submitted the [bug to Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=168162), but until then, I'd like to use this pattern, so I'm looking for a way around it that preserves most of this structure and the ability to use colspan above vertical text. The actual use case is more complex, so simply setting fixed widths somewhere is not a viable solution.

I attempted reimplementing the table as `display: flex` and nesting column within row-direction flex, but encountered the same bug, this time in Firefox as well.

Comment: Even your default example doesn't look the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: They both render it correctly. I'm not interested in things looking the same everywhere. I'm interested in working around major, show-stopping rendering errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple fix with jQuery (you can use pure js if you want, I think you can also do it using css (sass/less) but this is the solution I have.

First I check the userAgent, if it is Firefox set display to `inline-block` for `div` and `a`. Else just use flex.

For each `td div` and `td a` get child `div` or `a` width and assign to the width of parent `td`

```js
var display = 'flex';

if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") > -1) {
  display = 'inline-block';
}

$("td div, td a").each(function() {
  self = $(this);
  self.css('display', display);
  self.closest('td').width(self.width());
});
```

```css
.second td * {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=4>This cell has colspan=4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
    <td>
      <div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside block</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=4>This cell has colspan=4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
    <td id="thistd"><a id="this">Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
    <td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
    <td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
    <td><a>Writing-mode:vertical-rl inside inline</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Seems like `vertical-rl` is not supported very well... hummmmm try to avoid it for now I guess

https://www.w3.org/International/tests/repo/results/writing-mode-vertical

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, vertical-rl text is just vertical-lr text that is rotated 180 degrees around it's axis.

That can be achieved in 1 of 2 ways:

1. rotate the text using:

```css
transform: rotate(180deg)
```

2. a 180 deg rotation is equivalent the flipping the text over both X,Y axes

```css
transform: scale(-1,-1)
```

```css
.rl1 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rl2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
}

.lr {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}


/* JUST STYLING BELOW */

.styleContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.styleContainer .rl1,
.rl2 {
  color: green
}

.styleContainer .lr {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="styleContainer">
  <div class="rl1">
    solution1
  </div>
  <div class="rl2">
    solution2
  </div>
  <div class="lr">
    vertical-lr
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome so SO, WCP! Thanks for answer. Though it would be beneficial for future users if you could add a brief explanation how your solution works. That would serve the goals of StackOverflow even better.

Comment: Done! Thanks @Jan for keeping me honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an SVG image in your table header to force cross browser compatibility. Simple SVG's, not an svg produced by another app.